# Simple Collection With String Objects which allows search in 0(1) operation

Tags: java, search, collections, hashmap, processing-efficiency

I have simple collection of string objects might be around 10 elements , 
but i use this collection in production environment such that the we search for a given string in that collection millions of tiimes , 
what is the best collection or data structure we can use to get the best results so that seach operation can be performed in 0(1) time
we can use HashMap here but the order of search there is in constant time not 0(1) i want to make sure that search is 0(1).

Our data structure must return true if present , else false if not present

Comment: Constant time search? Yeah, a `HashMap` is probably your best bet.

Comment: Please ask separate questions _separately._

Comment: You should bencmark different solutions. A HashSet or similar is probably a good choice, but don't underestimate the speed of simple array searches when you have small collections. The overhead of generating a hashcode, looking up the hashcode and finding the correct bucket will also take time. A simple for-loop in an array of only 10 elements could potentially be a better choice, even if it's not constant.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `HashSet<String>` structure. The `contains()` operation has a complexity of O(1).

Comment: HashSet<String> does it ensure it gives 0(1) search complexity if so thats good . we will use it then

Comment: No it doesn't. Only if the hash codes of your objects are properly distributed. Therefore it's more something between O(n) and O(1), depending on the actual data and its implementation of hashCode(). But as said before, Hash(Map|Set) may be your best bet though.

Comment: Yeah i understand we cannot guarantee that its 0(1) its 0(c) time mostly . But can i design any custom data structure such that its gives in 0(1) . does guava collection set from google help like using a immutable collection ? does it help to reduce the memory foot print at least . since we use in a gaming industry per message if we can achieve it it would be a huge performance gain

Comment: `ImmutableSet` from Guava will [definitely reduce](http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures) the memory footprint (as compared to `HashSet`), and probably speed things up by a small constant factor.  Depending on a) the length of your strings, b) how often you get the same query more than once, c) whether or not you're willing to pay increased memory overhead, it _might_ be worthwhile to implement a trie.

Answer (score 1):

Constant time *is* O(1).  `HashMap` is fine.  (Or `HashSet`, depending on whether you need a `Set` or a `Map`.)

If your set is immutable, Guava's `ImmutableSet` will reduce memory footprint by a factor of ~3 (and probably give you a small constant factor of improved speed).

Comment: Yeah i can use HashSet HashMap as well , but we are in the process whether we should go with third party available libraries . Like Google Guava and Trove . Will using a Identity HashMap Help ? as using third party apis is tough call unless its worth . How far these Gauva and Trove APIs are used in industry

Comment: `IdentityHashMap` will almost certainly hurt you rather than helping you.  Guava is pretty extensively used; in particular, it's basically used in all Java-based Google services in production.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use HashSet/HashMap as previously suggested, you could write a [Radix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) implementation.

Comment: Yeah i can use HashSet HashMap as well , but we are in the process whether we should go with third party available libraries . Like Google Guava and Trove . Will using a Identity HashMap Help ? as using third party apis is tough call unless its worth . How far these Gauva and Trove APIs are used in industry